# Polite webscraping with a jsonlite function

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrap a page, but after a few scraps, the page block my access for an hour.

I read about the R package called [`{polite}`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/polite/versions/0.1.2) and it maybe can solve my problem.

But I'm failing to implement the function`s package in my code.

I did:

```r
#conection
url_ini <- paste0("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1&__d=11")
document_ini <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = url_ini)

#extracting information
id <- document_ini$graphql$user$id
end_cursor <- document_ini$graphql$user$edge_owner_to_timeline_media$page_info$end_cursor
         n1 <- 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=e769aa130647d2354c40ea6a439bfc08&variables={%22id%22:%22'
         n2 <- '%22,%22first%22:12,%22after%22:%22'
         n3 <- "%22}"
url <- noquote(paste0(n1, id, n2, end_cursor, n3))
document <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = url)
```

There are more code, but I think if I can do this part, I will be able to do the rest.

I tried without success things like this:

```r
url_ini <- paste0("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1&__d=11")

session <- polite::bow(url_ini)

document_ini <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = session) # doesn't work

responses <- map(session, ~polite::scrape(session,jsonlite::fromJSON))  # doesn't work
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean for you? Do you get an error message of some kind? It doesn't look like you've followed the basic example on the documentation page for `polite` that you linked to. Is there a reason you've not followed that example?

Comment: The website may be throttling the requests. Try adding `Sys.sleep(2)` to your loop to add a 2 second of delay between requests, this may help.

Comment: @Dave2e I believe the whole point of using the `polite` package is that it will do the rate limiting for you. Are you saying they should not use this package and do the delay manually?

Comment: I have not dug into “polite” deep enough to know its advantages.  Manually adding a delay could be simple way to test or resolve the problem.

Comment: @Dave2e and @MrFlick , thanks for your answers! I did try to use Sys.sleep(2) and I could scrap a little more, but in some point I also got blocked. I saw a few examples of the use of `polite`, but I can`t apply to my case.

Comment: Tried again with more time, but I have no progress. I can't scrap all the data I need. Instagram blocks me after a few time.